# How to put a banner ad between post 1 and post 2 on homepage only

Tags: themes, homepage

Wordpress **Swift Theme** is installed on my My site http://tech-ticks.info

From last few days, I am trying to find a solution to put an ad banner on homepage only between post1 and post 2. I have already tried on worpress support forum.

Can anyone here help me out as i don't have much knowledge about PHP.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You will not to post some code or a better example , please have a look at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 4):

Register a widget, and call it on the front-page when the `the_post` action is called second time:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wpse_80202_register_banner_widget' );
function wpse_80202_register_banner_widget()
{
    // used on the first page of main loop only
    register_sidebar(
        array (
            'name'          => 'Banner front-page ',
            'id'            => 'frontpage_banner',
            'before_widget' => '<div class="frontpage-banner">',
            'after_widget'  => '</div>'
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'loop_start', 'wpse_80202_show_banner_widget' );

function wpse_80202_show_banner_widget()
{
    static $count = 0;
    if ( ! is_front_page() )
        return;

    if ( 'loop_start' === current_filter() )
    {
        add_action( 'the_post', __FUNCTION__ );
        return;
    }

    $count += 1;

    if ( 2 === $count )
    {
        dynamic_sidebar( 'frontpage_banner' );
        remove_action( 'the_post', __FUNCTION__ );
    }
}
```

I would use the **Text** widget for that:

[image]

Another variant of this code here: [Add Adsense code in index.php](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84250/add-adsense-code-in-index-php/84302#84302)